# Angular 2 - child routes with router outlet

Tags: angular

I have a component that gets loaded when the route changes to 'main'.
I have defined in its routes a child route called 'test'

When the route is set to main/test I want the test component to be loaded within the main component. Inside the main component I have a router outlet to display the child component.

Here is my main.routes.ts:

```
    import { Route } from '@angular/router';
    import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
    import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
    import { SessionGuard } from '../../services/session/session.guard';

    export const MainRoutes: Route[] = [
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [SessionGuard],
        children: [
      {   path: 'test', component: TestComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

In the main components html I have:

```
Main
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The error I am getting is:
cannot match any routes main/test

Button to trigger route change:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="changeRoute('main/test');" >Test</button>
```

Method to change route:

```
changeRoute(route: string) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.router.navigate([route]);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you redirect to test? is it a default child route wihin maincomponent?

Comment: Yes it is a child component. In main I have <router-outlet></router-outlet>. I use a button to redirect, also tried with just the address bar.

Comment: So please also post how button works? what is your code?

Comment: please update in your question. I think I got your problem.

Comment: just add `{   path: ' ', component: TestComponent }` and check.

Comment: I had tried this earlier actually. What I did now was for the path '' I set the component to null so that nothing gets shown. When I visit the path main/test I now see the correct component, the error now is that when visiting the route it causes the application to reload...

Comment: sorted it, it was reloading when using the route change through a primeng component not just the button. please write the answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`router-outlet`** can not be empty. It means when you redirect to main component, you don't have any default child router set. You just need to set it as shown below,

```
export const MainRoutes: Route[] = [
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [SessionGuard],
        children: [
                     {path:'',redirectTo:'test', pathMatch: 'full'},
                     {path: 'test', component: TestComponent }
    ]
```

And if you want to redirect to **`test`** with button's click event only then you should use below configuration,

```
export const MainRoutes: Route[] = [
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [SessionGuard],
        children: [
                     {path:'',component:null},     //<<<<### here with null value
                     {path: 'test', component: TestComponent }
    ]
```